# If WebRTC Application is started in between a Phone Call, the peer who is on call is not able to hear anything even after ending that call

Tags: browser, webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I have an application on top of WebRTC.  If a peer (A) clicks on the link to the application and starts it in the middle of a phone call, then that peer (A) is getting connected to peer (B) successfully. Even after ending the call, Peer A is not able to hear Peer B whereas Peer-B is able to see the video as well as hear the audio of Peer - A. The application works perfectly if the PeerConnection was created without any ongoing phone call.

I have tried to [restart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/restartIce)/[createOffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createOffer) the ICE and tried to acquire the user-media again and [replace the tracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpSender/replaceTrack). But nothing works.

1. Is there a way I can find out in browser that there is an ongoing call so that I can prevent the customer from even initiating the RTCPeerConnection?
2. How to recover from this situation of no-audio at PeerA even after hanging up the call

Answer (score 0):

This is a known Chrome bug, see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1285805&)